# How do scientists measure miniscule constants like the mass and charge and speed of an electron?

Tags: mass, charge, measurements, speed

What can measure the extremely tiny mass of an electron? Is it through indirect means? The same goes for charge. The pull of a single electron must be infinitely small. And if one is to attempt to find the very high speeds of electrons, doesn't one have to have a machine that can measure extremely short amounts of time and length accurately?

Comment: Here's an interesting [article](http://www.chemteam.info/AtomicStructure/Determine-electron-charge.html) on the matter of charge. As for mass, you can get that from the curvature of an electron beam in a magnetic field.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment

Comment: Carefully. Very, *very* carefully.

Comment: @cag Well, you get the mass/charge ratio from the curvature, then you do the oil drop experiment and between them get the mass. (That was the historical order, BTW.)